# The Developement Server Returned Error 500

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

First of all when I create a project and run it using:

```
react-native run-android
```

It works just fine but now when I have added some code for login screen it gives me this error:

```
Development Server Returned Error 500
```

I am new to React-native and I am not able to understand how to fix it, add to that I am not able to attach my debugger to visual Code so I don't need to run `"RUN command"` to test my app...

Can anyone help me?

- [Error code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhyjR.jpg)
- [Continuation of error code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydIUU.jpg)
- [2nd Continuation of Error code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZcnj.png)

Comment: Error code 500 / Continuation of Error code 500 / 2nd Continuation of Error code 500 

are Images kindly check them to see what error I have and how can I solve it!!

Answer (score 0):

What does your metro bundler say? It'll be the thing that says "Loading dependency Graph... done"